# Python, pandas.read_csv on large csv file with 10 Million rows from Google Drive file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, google-drive-api, google-bigquery

I extracted a .csv file from Google Bigquery of 2 columns and 10 Million rows.

I have downloaded the file locally as a .csv with the size of 170Mb, then I uploaded the file to Google Drive, and I want to use pandas.read_csv() function to read it into pandas DataFrame in my Jupyter Notebook.

Here is the code I used, with specific fileID that I wanna read.

```
# read into pandasDF from .csv stored on Google Drive.
follow_network_df = pd.read_csv("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1WqHWdgMVLPKVbFzIIprBBhe3I9faq4HA")
```

Then here is what I got: 
[image]

It seems the 170Mb csv file is read as an html link?

While when I tried the same code with another csv file of 40Mb, it worked perfectly

```
# another csv file of 40Mb.
user_behavior_df = pd.read_csv("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1NT3HZmrrbgUVBz5o6z_JwW5A5vRXOgJo")
```

[image]

Can anyone give me some hint on the root cause of the difference? 
Any ideas on how to read a csv file of 10 Million rows and 170Mb from online storage? I know it's possible to just read the 10 Million rows into pandasDF by just using the BigQuery interface or from local machine, but I have to include this as part of my submission, so it's only possible for me to read from online source.

Comment: The 170mb file is not loading but it looks like it gives a virus warning in the html.. please copy and paste code as images do not help at all....

Comment: @johnashu Hi, honestly the only line of code I am having problem is: `follow_network_df = pd.read_csv("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1WqHWdgMVLPKVbFzIIprBBhe3I9faq4HA")
`  The url inside the bracket can be used to access the file on google drive. Thanks

Comment: @johnashu I get around this by using Dropbox link instead.

Comment: read it by chunk

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your first file is too large for Google Drive to scan for viruses, so there's a user prompt that gets displayed instead of the actual file. You can see this if you access the first file's link.

I'd say click on the user prompt and use the following url with `pd.read_csv`.

Comment: Hi, following the suggestion, I clicked on the file in google drive, clicked on the "Download" button, and get the url. With that url, I tried with pd.read_csv() again. `https://doc-04-2k-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/0rmotvlinl4cc8h2a5bls9fhliamgfgi/oh0k0d8arep7pfubo8v2etubhom0rms3/1522800000000/12586420623118277152/12586420623118277152/1QX5SbJxrMa59q97534scstIrsxmh0IK_?e=download`  But it raised error: `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 6, saw 2`

Comment: I get around this by using Dropbox link instead.